# How to customize expressionHandler and accessDecisionManager in Spring Security 6

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm upgrading an application to Spring Boot 3.x, Security 6.x replacing the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` with a `SecurityFilterChain` bean.

In my previous config I customized the expressionHandler and accessDecisionManager this way:

```
public class CustomSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        ...
        ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry authorizeRequests = http.antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests();

        authorizeRequests.expressionHandler(webSecurityExpressionHandler());
        ...
        authorizeRequests.accessDecisionManager(accessDecisionManager(webSecurityExpressionHandler()));
```

Moving to the bean I have:

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        ...
         http.securityMatcher("/**")
                        .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                           ???
```

The problem is that the auth lambda field doesn't provice access to set the expressionHandler and accessDecisionManager.

How can I configure them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Security 6 [has deprecated the usage of](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/architecture.html#_the_authorizationmanager) the `AccessDecissionManager` and `AccessDecisionVoter`.

The recommended approach is to implement an `AuthorizationManager`.

```java
public class CustomAuthorizationManager implements AuthorizationManager<RequestAuthorizationContext> {

    @Override
    public AuthorizationDecision check(Supplier authentication, RequestAuthorizationContext object) {
        ...
        return new AuthorizationDecision(decision);
    }
```

With it we can customize the authorization logic of the `.authorizeHttpRequest()` matchers:

```java
http.securityMatcher("/**")
     .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
         auth.requestMatchers("/someurl").access(authorizationManager)
     });
```

Regarding the `expressionHandler`, it was as easy as definying it as a bean:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityExpressionHandler<FilterInvocation> customWebSecurityExpressionHandler() {
    CustomWebSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new CustomWebSecurityExpressionHandler();
    expressionHandler.setDefaultRolePrefix("");
    return expressionHandler;
}
```

Comment: how can we inject AccessDecisionVoter<FilterInvocation> into CustomAuthorizationManager? 

I am trying to create a composite custom authorization manager which does a ConsensusBased voting on every request before it casts AuthorizationDecision